# Mocking default export is failing but named export not

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, mocking

I have a lets say file.js having code something like this

```
const myFunc = () => {
    return {
        func1: () => {},
        func2: () => {}
    }
}

export const myObject = {
 key: ''
};

export default myFunc();
```

I am trying to mock this exports in my test using jest. Lets say file.test.js is test file.

```
jest.mock('./path/file', () => {
    return {
         default: {
              func1: jest.fn(),
              func2: jest.fn()
         },
         myObject: {}
    };
});
```

But when my tests is running then it is throwing me error saying `_File.default.func1 is not a function`.

How can I correctly mock my js file having both default and named exports?

Comment: `func1: jest.fn()` creates a property called `func1` with the **result of calling** `jets.fn()` ... - since you are calling the function in that code ... unless calling `jest.fn()` returns a function,  remove the `()` - alternatively `func1: () => { return jest.fn();}` - which looks just like the code in `file.js` now

Comment: @JaromandaX It did work thanks. But every other place I am using jest.fn() for passing as function for spying. Why is it not breaking there?

Comment: I can't see every other place you use it so I can't help you understand your own code ... if you want to CALL a function you do `fn()` - if you want to pass a function to something, you use `fn`

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for saving my day.

Comment: @JaromandaX [`jest.fn()` *does* return a function](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestfnimplementation), so this should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
const myFunc = () => {
  return {
    func1: () => {},
    func2: () => {},
  };
};

export const myObject = {
  key: '',
};

export default myFunc();
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import fns, { myObject } from './';

jest.mock('./', () => {
  return {
    myObject: { key: 'teresa teng' },
    func1: jest.fn(),
    func2: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe('64003254', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(fns.func1)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(fns.func2)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(myObject.key).toBe('teresa teng');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64003254/index.test.ts (11.809s)
  64003254
    ✓ should pass (6ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.572s
```